# How to pass Sencha Touch 2 "POST" Ext.Ajax.Request params to default Rails controller?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, sencha-touch-2, parameter-passing

I have a form in Sencha Touch 2 and I'm trying to pass the values to a POST method using the 'Ext.Ajax.request' to a Ruby on Rails Server hosted on Heroku:

```
var name = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalName').getValue(), 
    details = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalDetails').getValue(),
    city = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalCity').getValue(),
    period = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalPeriod').getValue(),
    timings = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalTiming').getValue(),
    telephone = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalTelephone').getValue(),
    id = Ext.getCmp('txtFestivalId').getValue() 

Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://anyapp.herokuapp.com/festivals.json',
        method: 'POST',
        type:'json',
        params: 
        {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            details: details,
            city: city,
            period: period,
            timings: timings,
            telephone: telephone
        },
        callback: this.somecallbackfunction
        scope: this
    });
```

I want to keep my Ruby on Rails controller code for the create function as the default, like so:

```
# POST /festivals
# POST /festivals.json
def create
@festival = Festival.new(params[:festiva])

respond_to do |format|
  if @festival.save
    format.html { redirect_to @festival, notice: 'Festival was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @festival, status: :created, location: @festival }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @festival.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

How can I reformat the params in the Sencha code so that it passes into the Ruby on Rails controller in a way that works for both the RoR desktop app and Sencha app?

I have already figured that changing the RoR controller to this works:

```
def create
@festival = Festival.new(:name => params[:name], :details => params[:details], :city =>
params[:city], :period => params[:period], :timings => params[:timings], :telephone => 
params[:telephone])
```

However, when I do that, the web app side gets broken and it will save blank records for @festival.  But the Sencha app would be able to successfully save and update records to the RoR database. What is going on?

This was a really good reference but I'm not sure how it works and I don't want to mess with underscore.js:
https://gist.github.com/1506953

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Still haven't figured this out unfortunately.  Can anyone help?